# I'm Unable to perform a PHP insert query

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to insert the data in a MYSQL database but it seems that my query is not working i've tried all other methods but nothing is working for me ,Here is the PHP that i'm using

```
<?php
 $server="localhost";
$database="hospital";
$login="root";
$password="";
$connexion=mysql_connect ($server, $login, $password) or die ('Server cannot be found'.mysql_error ( ));
mysql_select_db ($database,$connexion)or die ('database cannot be found'.mysql_error( ));
$a= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['doctorname']);
$b = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['writtendate']);
$c = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['hospitalname']);
$d = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['patientname']);
$e = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dateofbirth']);
$f= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cardnumber']);
$g = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['groupname']);
$h = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['drug1']);
$i = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['drug2']);
$j = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['drug3']);
$k = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['drug4']);
$l = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['amount1']);
$m = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['amount2']);
$n = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['amount3']);
$f = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['principalmembersname']);



if(@$_POST['submit'])
{

$query="insert into uap(doctorname,writtendate,hospitalname,patientname,dateofbirth,cardnumber,groupname,principalmembersname,drug1,drug2,drug3,drug4,amount1,amount2,amount3) values ('$_POST[doctorname]','$_POST[writtendate]','$_POST[hospitalname]','$_POST[patientname]','$_POST[dateofbirth]','$_POST[cardnumber]','$_POST[groupname]','$_POST[principalmembersname]','$_POST[drug1]','$_POST[drug2]','$_POST[drug3]','$_POST[drug4]','$_POST[amount1]','$_POST[amount2]','$_POST[amount3]')";
$answer=mysql_db_query ($database, $query);
}
mysql_close ($connexion);
?>
```

Comment: Where to begin.... 1) If you have variables `$a` through `$o` (you used `$f` twice...), don't you think there'd be a better way to handle things? 2) `mysql_*` is deprecated, don't use it. Switch to `mysqli_*` or PDO. 3) What did you try to debug this? What's the error returned? 4) You escape all that stuff and then **still** use `$_POST` in your query?

Comment: Why are you escaping all those variables and not using them ? try `mysql_error()` and give us the result. plus use `mysqli` instead `mysql` is deprecated

Comment: @MehdiBounya it's not _becoming_ deprecated, it already _is_ deprecated, and has been deprecated for years! It doesn't even exist on current PHP releases.

Comment: @sidyll yeah actually when i posted the comment i realized my mistake, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @MehdiBounya No problem :) My intention is not to correct you, my intention is to raise awareness to this fact to the questioner. It amazes me how much these deprecated interfaces are still being used.

Comment: @sidyll I have no problem with people correcting me, actually the reason you still see these deprecated functions is schools, they are not up to date, at least in my country students are still studying the old php

Answer (score 2):

To get you on the right track on using PDO and prepared statements (with named placeholders in this case):

```
<?php

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=databasename', 'username', 'password');

$statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `uap` (`doctorname`,`writtendate`,`hospitalname`,`patientname`,`dateofbirth`,`cardnumber`,`groupname`,`principalmembersname`,`drug1`,`drug2`,`drug3`,`drug4`,`amount1`,`amount2`,`amount3`) VALUES (:doctorname, :writtendate, :hospitalname, :patientname, :dateofbirth, :cardnumber, :groupname, :principalmembersname, :drug1, :drug2, :drug3, :drug4, :amount1, :amount2, :amount3)");

$result = $statement->execute(
    array(
        'doctorname' => $_POST['doctorname'],
        'writtendate' => $_POST['writtendate'],
        'hospitalname' => $_POST['hospitalname'],
        'patientname' => $_POST['patientname'],
        'dateofbirth' => $_POST['dateofbirth'],
        'cardnumber' => $_POST['cardnumber'],
        'groupname' => $_POST['groupname'],
        'principalmembersname' => $_POST['principalmembersname'],
        'drug1' => $_POST['drug1'],
        'drug2' => $_POST['drug2'],
        'drug3' => $_POST['drug3'],
        'drug4' => $_POST['drug4'],
        'amount1' => $_POST['amount1'],
        'amount2' => $_POST['amount2'],
        'amount3' => $_POST['amount3']
    )
);

if (!$result)
{
    echo "SQL Error <br/>";
    echo $statement->queryString."<br/>";
    echo $statement->errorInfo()[2];
}
```

Although I still think your schema could use some optimization (eg. a dedicated drug table with a many-to-many relation to patients or whatever this is)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code that you have above mainly lies in string concatenation. In your `$query` variable you have two primary issues:

First you have combined array syntax within a quoted string:
`$query = "insert into uap (...) values ('$_POST[doctorname]')"`

Second the when you reference arrays like `$_POST[doctorname]` (without the quotes around the keys) PHP assumes that the unquoted string is a constant that contains the same value as its name. That makes this seem like proper code, but it is actually very, VERY messy.

The PHP interpreter cannot understand exactly what you are trying to do in this case and ends up stopping concatenation at the $_POST variable. So your resultant string probably looks something like this: `insert into uap (...) values ('array[doctorname]')`. You can correct this by using braces to tell the PHP interpreter to use the whole array syntax in the string:
`$query = "insert into uap (...) values ('{$_POST['doctorname']}')"` or by using the concatenation `.` operator to perform proper string concatenation: `$query = 'insert into uap (...) values ('".$_POST['doctorname']."')"`.

You simplest solution however, is to use the variables that you had specified above in your code. You final `$query` variable should look something like this (which will also use the `mysql_escape_string() function that you used above):

```
<?php
$server="localhost";
$database="hospital";
$login="root";
$password="";
$connexion=mysql_connect ($server, $login, $password) or die ('Server cannot be found'.mysql_error ( ));
mysql_select_db ($database,$connexion)or die ('database cannot be found'.mysql_error( ));
$doctorname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['doctorname']);
$writtendate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['writtendate']);
$hospitalname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['hospitalname']);
$patientname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['patientname']);
$datofbirth = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dateofbirth']);
$cardnumber = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cardnumber']);
$groupname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['groupname']);
$drug1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['drug1']);
$drug2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['drug2']);
$drug3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['drug3']);
$drug4 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['drug4']);
$amount1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['amount1']);
$amount2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['amount2']);
$amount3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['amount3']);
$principlemembersname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['principalmembersname']);

if(@$_POST['submit'])
{
    $query = "insert into uap(doctorname,writtendate,hospitalname,patientname,dateofbirth,cardnumber,groupname,principalmembersname,drug1,drug2,drug3,drug4,amount1,amount2,amount3)
                      values ('$doctorname','$writtendate','$hospitalname','$patientname','$datofbirth','$cardnumber','$groupname','$principlemembersname','$drug1','$drug2','$drug3','$drug4','$amount1','$amount2','$amount3')";
    $answer=mysql_db_query ($database, $query);
}
mysql_close ($connexion);
?>
```

As noted by other users it would be a good idea to convert this code to use PDO and prepared statements as the `mysql` functions in PHP are deprecated.

Good luck! I hope this helps!

Comment: Actually, using variables that way [works fine](https://3v4l.org/OnJBT) in all PHP versions (you do need the curly bracers when you're dealing with indizes using special chars like `-`), although I agree OPs code is not clean at all. On the other hand: It's 2017, stop posting **answers** using `mysql_*`, they have been deprecated for nearly 8 years.